# Cannot prettify html code with sublime text nor beautiful soup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape some website for information. i have saved the page I want to scrape as .html file and have opened it with `sublime text` but there are some parts that cannot be displayed in a prettified way ; I have the same problem when trying to use `beautifulsoup` ; see picture below (I cannot really share full code since it's disclosing private info).

[image]

Comment: could you please include some of your code

Comment: Precisely I'd rather not ; it's actually the html code for a facebook public page...

Comment: `beautifulsoup` doesn't need prettify code to work.

Comment: @furas true but I need prettified code to detect the key for the information I am looking for...

Comment: open page in web browser, go to DevTools (Chrome/Firefox) and you can see nice formatted HTML. I always use DevTools to check HTML and to get path for scraping. DevTool can even give xpath or css selector for selected element. Or I can use JavaScript `document.getElementByXXX` to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Just feed the HTML as a multiline string to `BeautifulSoup` object and use `soup.prettify()`. That should work. However beautifulsoup has default indentation to 2 spaces. So if you want custom indent you can writeup a little wrapper like this:

```
def indentPrettify(soup, indent=4):
    # where desired_indent is number of spaces as an int()
    pretty_soup = str()
    previous_indent = 0
    # iterate over each line of a prettified soup
    for line in soup.prettify().split("\n"):
        # returns the index for the opening html tag '<'
        current_indent = str(line).find("<")
        # which is also represents the number of spaces in the lines indentation
        if current_indent == -1 or current_indent > previous_indent + 2:
            current_indent = previous_indent + 1
            # str.find() will equal -1 when no '<' is found. This means the line is some kind
            # of text or script instead of an HTML element and should be treated as a child
            # of the previous line. also, current_indent should never be more than previous + 1.
        previous_indent = current_indent
        pretty_soup += writeOut(line, current_indent, indent)
    return pretty_soup

def writeOut(line, current_indent, desired_indent):
    new_line = ""
    spaces_to_add = (current_indent * desired_indent) - current_indent
    if spaces_to_add > 0:
        for i in range(spaces_to_add):
            new_line += " "
    new_line += str(line) + "\n"
    return new_line
```